# how can you get a server callback on windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I simply want to be able to make a callback on a function in the windows phone code from the server side when something is being updated there. Examples abound on the Internet make use of wsDualHttpBinding, but some wise man has decided to remove support for that from the windows store application API list. I can't find any other way to get the same functionality, does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning behind not allowing for internet based callbacks is that it puts a big drain on the phone's battery to be constantly listening for them. Instead, they allow you to run `PeriodicTask`'s that will let you occasionally call a server to poll whether there is a change.

Alternatively you could use their notification service:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: thanks, but polling will introduce a latency with the polling interval as a maximum. I'm not familiar with the notification system, but from a quick glance at the description it seems overly complicated, I think I will just mimic the slow load technique...  http://www.obviously.com/tech_tips/slow_load_technique.html (I need a temporarily open communication channel, it will always cost CPU power)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    public void Initialize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(done);
    }
    public string version = "1.0.0";
    public void done(object sender, System.Net.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (version != e.Result)
        {
            //Do your code here
        }
    }
```

You can create a place online that stores the current version then check on start up.